# Кириллица в windows 10

Tags: windows, кодировка, windows-10, кириллица

Есть такая проблема, у некоторых файлов, которые скачивал названия не отображаются (конкретно символы кириллицы), при этом при создании таких файлов на ПК все хорошо с отображением.

Пример таких файлов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема относительно распространенная, просто надо поменять кодировку (вероятно).

Только вот перепробовал много всего, ничего не помогло:

- Снес `7zip`, поставил `Winrar`
- Изменил несколько значений реестра

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- В настройках язык стоит русский (не менял)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Вводил в команду `sfc /scannow`. Она нашла какую то ошибку, исправила, но это не помогло.

Как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 дня мучений и решение нашлось `Панель управления` -> `Часы и регион` -> `Изменение параметров даты и времени` -> `Дополнительно` -> `Изменить язык системы` -> и вот тут надо было убрать галочку с этой штуки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`Бета версия` и все заработало после перезагрузки.

Может быть кому-нибудь поможет.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо!! Я тоже чего только не перепробовала. Мне изначально поставили винду на английском, но всё те же проблемы с отображением. Этот шаг (решение в 1-м ответе) стал первым

[image: Как путь к нужному пункту выглядит в англоязычной версии]

А дальше помог совет с сайта ремонтка.про

[image: алгоритм с сайта ремонтка.про]

После каждого изменения была перезагрузка компа